# How to zoom (and apply grid on) subfigures

Tags: tikz-pgf, floats, subfloats, zooming

So I have folders containing triplets of images which all have the same style as shown in an example below

[image: Example image]

It is basically an automatically generated image and a color-bar besides it.
I want to display triplets of images in my LaTeX document with a single color-bar - this is easily achievable using subfloats

```
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[trim = 21mm 22mm 38mm 14mm, clip]{img/batch01/dist01}
\caption{$r=1$}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[trim = 21mm 22mm 38mm 14mm, clip]{img/batch01/dist02}
\caption{$r=11$}
\end{subfigure}\hspace{20pt}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[trim = 21mm 22mm 23mm 14mm, clip]{img/batch01/dist03}
\caption{$r=21$}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Distances ...}
\end{figure}
```

[image: Triplet example]

But how should I make my life easier if I want to zoom in the data? Let's say to show only the middle 9-th of the square like this
[image: Zoomed triplet example]

The example above was created using photo editing software. Unfortunately it would take a ridiculous amount of time for me to create them all like that.

What would you suggest? Maybe it is even possible to apply some kind of a grid to make individual pixels more distinctive (not sure about this one, may be too complicated and not worth it).

Comment: `\includegraphics` provides a `scale` option. To zoom your picture, you may use this `scale` option combined with `clip` and `trim` options (and adapted values).

Comment: @Pranasas did Paul's suggestions help you to solve this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because inactive questioner.